# How to build a constructor for a matrix type in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, matrix, constructor

I'm a beginner in C++, and as a learning exercise I'm trying to write a library for doing matrix math (matrix multiplication, invertion and the like).
The first thing I want to do is to define a class "Matrix", which members are "rows"- the number of rows in the matrix, "cols"-the number of columns in the matrix, and "_matrix"-an array containing the elements of the matrix.
The problem is I don't have any idea how to build the constructor.
Can I write something like "Matrix(m,n,array)"? how do I make sure the array actually contains m*n elements?
I would love some guidence on how to procceed (well.. how to begin if I'm being honest :) )

thanks!

Comment: By default your class should manage the array yourself, and not let users pass in any array. After you have that working, then you can add a constructor to copy from an external array, but then you have to trues that the user passes in valid dimensions, and if the user doesn't well that's the users fault and not yours.

Comment: I highly recommend searching the internet for examples.  You could do something like "c++ matrix source".

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! This question might not be the best fit for stack overflow unfortunately. The best questions are organized around a very concrete programming problem, which might have some code, which is working or not. "Guidance for how to begin" is not what stackoverflow provides -- how to begin is largely a matter of opinion, and those questions tend to get downvoted. It's better to come back once you are knee deep in it and you have some code to show.

Comment: By the way, a Matrix is a separate object than an array; like a stack is not an array (but can be implemented using one).  I recommend adjusting your question's title (something like "Implementing Matrix constructor").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another answer provides a typical solution one would expect a `Matrix` class constructor to have (i.e. `Matrix(unsigned, unsigned)`).

If you are doing it as an exercise and you are serious about learnig C++, I would *also* suggest implementing the following contructor:

```
Matrix(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> init_list);
```

Therefore you could build your object like that:

```
Matrix m({{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}});
```

Note that you could take size of the constructed matrix straight from the `std::initializer_list`s provided and you could easily build templated matrices that way.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.
I'm not farmiliar with the syntex of the second constructor you suggested, but I'll look it up.

Answer (score 1):

If I were using a matrix, I would expect a constructor like:

```
Matrix(unsigned int maximum_rows, unsigned int maximum_columns);
```

I don't care if the matrix is implemented by array, list or other data structure.  I told it the size, so construct one.

**Edit 1:**
You want to *hide* the implementation of the Matrix from the user.  The implementation of the constructor depends on your implementation.

The implementation may be different for a lower triangular matrix than a generic one.  You may decide on a `vector` of `vectors`, a 2 dimensional array, a one dimensional array or a linked list.

I as the user don't really care how it's implemented.  All I care is that the expected Matrix functionalities are implemented *correctly*, and in some cases, efficiently.  So I may expect an overloaded `operator +` or an `add` method or both.

Again, search the internet to see examples of how other people have implemented a matrix.

**Edit 2:**
There may be cases where you want to have one class for the functionality and another class for the implementation.  In that case, you may want to pass the implementation to the Matrix's constructor.  (I would suggest using a reference to a base class the describes the implementation interface).  But that may be overkill for what you need.